# comparing 2 data field in mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

This is my database

[image: database]

i want to comparing 2 date time datatype (datetime_comp & date_time)
simple comparison. etc : date1 > date 2 = "On_Time"

but my problem is, i need to compare the data 1 by 1 (loop for sure)
and this is my code

```
from datetime import datetime
import pymysql
import time

#Declare Connection
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port='', user='root', passwd='', db='tes_coba', use_unicode=True, charset="utf8mb4")
cur = conn.cursor()

EW = "Tepat Waktu"
LW = "Tidak Tepat Waktu"

#get data from database
cur.execute("SELECT datetime_comp FROM `tweet2`")
row1 = cur.fetchall()
cur.execute("SELECT date_time FROM `tweet2`")
row2 = cur.fetchall()

n  = 1

for date1 in row1:
    print(date1)

for date2 in row2:
    print(date2)

if date1 > date2:
    Result=EW
elif date1 < date2:
    Result=LW

print(Result)
cur.execute("UPDATE tweet2 SET on_time=%s WHERE no=%s AND relevance='Relevan'",(str(Result), str(n)))
n = n + 1


conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

and the result is, the comparison code only work with last data in database, because the comparison code does not looping for sure (confusing)

but if i put the comparison code to one if the looping process,

```
for date1 in row1:
    print(date1)

for date2 in row2:
    print(date2)

    if date1 > date2:
        Result=EW
    elif date1 < date2:
        Result=LW
```

only the last data compare with all data

Comment: Because you are comparing it out of the loop!

Comment: i knew it for sure, but if i comparing inside the loop, only the last database comparing with the loop data (if u know what i mean)

Comment: @experiment forgot to mention. if u have any solution sir ?

Comment: you will get `NameError` if `date1` == `date2`

Comment: also it will be better to `SELECT` both columns in one query like `SELECT datetime_comp, date_time FROM tweet2` and iterate over tuples

Comment: @Nanda I have posted an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you do not need two separate queries to match two columns of the same table. It can be done in the same query.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `tweet2`")
records = cur.fetchall()
```

iterate the records:

```
for record in records:
    if record[2] < record[5]: # I'm assuming the column index 2 and 5 have the relevant table column values
        do something here
    else:
        do something else here
```

Comment: really thanks to you man, this is work. i didnt know how to mention the record before. thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

Firstly load your table into a dataframe and np.where to compare columns to form a new column

```
import pymysql
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Declare Connection
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port='', user='root', passwd='', db='tes_coba', use_unicode=True, charset="utf8mb4")


query = "SELECT date_time,datetime_comp FROM tweet2"
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

df['result'] = np.where(df['datetime_comp']>df["date_time"], 'Tepat Waktu', 'Tidak Tepat Waktu')
```

I hope it works for you!

Comment: (ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!) error sir @experiment. could you help with pymysql library ?

Comment: @Nanda Don`t call me sir/ma`am! What kind of data you get when you run the query SELECT date_time,datetime_comp FROM `tweet2` ?

Comment: okay sorry man :D, its going wrong when df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall()) and pop the error

Comment: Why do we need pandas and np for such task?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal There are other solutions as well. I prefer loading the data to dataframes to do the processing part.As nanda wanted an extra column of results ,using dataframes we can get that effectively!

Comment: @experiment thanks my man, the problem is solved. i appreciated your responses, thanks :D